# Improving Terrain Generation Time in C#

Tags: c#, performance, random, graphics

I am working on making my code run smoother, since I will be using it a lot in a game in development, but I am stumped. Is there any way I could make this run faster? Improvements to the terrain generation and image drawing are both welcome.

```
internal class Terrain
{
    public Terrain(Content content)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int seed = random.Next(content.MaxSeed - content.MinSeed) + content.MinSeed;
        int offset = 10000;
        int sideLength = content.MapSize - 1;
        int halfSideLength;
        int average;
        int yTop;
        int yBottom;

        content.Map[0 , 0] = seed;
        content.Map[content.MapSize - 1 , 0] = seed;
        content.Map[0 , content.MapSize - 1] = seed;
        content.Map[content.MapSize - 1  , content.MapSize - 1] = seed;

        content.Screen = "GeneratingTerrain";
        while (sideLength > 0)
        {
            halfSideLength = sideLength / 2;

            for (int x = 0; x < content.MapSize - 1; x += sideLength)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < content.MapSize - 1; y += sideLength)
                {
                    average = content.Map[x , y]
                            + content.Map[x + sideLength , y]
                            + content.Map[x , y + sideLength]
                            + content.Map[x + sideLength , y + sideLength];
                    average /= 4;

                    if (random.NextDouble() >= 0.5)
                    {
                        average += random.Next(offset);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        average -= random.Next(offset);
                    }

                    content.Map[x + halfSideLength , y + halfSideLength] = average;
                }
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < content.MapSize - 1; x += sideLength)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < content.MapSize; y += sideLength)
                {
                    yTop = y - halfSideLength;
                    yBottom = y + halfSideLength;

                    if (yTop < 0) yTop = y + halfSideLength;
                    if (yBottom > content.MapSize - 1) yBottom = y - halfSideLength;

                    average = content.Map[x , y]
                            + content.Map[x + sideLength  , y]
                            + content.Map[x + halfSideLength , yTop]
                            + content.Map[x + halfSideLength , yBottom];
                    average /= 4;

                    content.Map[x + halfSideLength , y] = average;
                }
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < content.MapSize; x += sideLength)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < content.MapSize - 1; y += sideLength)
                {
                    int xRight = x + halfSideLength;

                    if (xRight > content.MapSize - 1) xRight = x - halfSideLength;

                    average = content.Map[x , y]
                            + content.Map[x , y + sideLength]
                            + content.Map[xRight , y + halfSideLength]
                            + content.Map[xRight , y + halfSideLength];
                    average /= 4;

                    content.Map[x , y + halfSideLength] = average;

                }
            }

            offset /= 2;
            sideLength /= 2;
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < content.MapSize; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < content.MapSize; y++)
            {
                content.Map[x , y] = (content.Colors.Length - 1) - content.Map[x , y] / 500;
                if (content.Map[x , y] < 0)
                {
                    content.Map[x , y] = 0;
                }
                else if (content.Map[x, y] > 20)
                {
                    content.Map[x , y] = 20;
                }
            }
        }
        content.Screen = "DrawingMap";
        Graphics imageDrawer = Graphics.FromImage(content.Overworld);

        for (int x = 0; x < (content.MapSize - 1) * content.TileSize; x += content.TileSize)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < (content.MapSize - 1) * content.TileSize; y += content.TileSize)
            {
                content.brush.Color = content.Colors[content.Map[x, y]];
                imageDrawer.FillRectangle(content.brush, x, y, content.TileSize, content.TileSize);
            }
        }
        content.Screen = "OverWorld";
    }
}
```

Example of generated Terrain:[image: Terrain]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of a generated map? It would be helpful.

Comment: @bazola I added an example.

Comment: Small notes, if you are dividing by powers of 2 I think it would be faster to shift right >> 1 equates to / 2, >> 2 == /4 etc. 

I'm not sure if the 500 is specifically chosen, but 512 is a power of two that is really close to it. If you can change the code so that it is 512, ie nothing else depends on that being precisely 500, you can change it to a right shift.

I'm not sure if it is faster, but the lines checking if content.Map is > 0 and less than 20 could be shortened by checking if content.Colors.Length - 1 < content.Map[x , y], set to 0, otherwise calculation

Comment: @spyr03 since this is c#, there are two compilers between the source code and the machine code.  I am pretty sure the machine code will be the same regardless of whether the source code uses a shift or division by a power of two.  This is a pretty standard optimization and all the jitted code I've ever seen used it.  The only reason to use a shift in c# code is if it makes the code more readable, which it generally only does when the code is concerned with actual bit twiddling.

Comment: Have you profiled the code?  That will tell you where to concentrate.  10 to 1 arithmetic is not your problem.  I suspect that the final pass to modify the out-of-range values is wasteful.  If you can modify the algorithm so they are guaranteed to be in range it would be better (by using Math.Min and Math.Max, perhaps).

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm for iterating over the map is quite strange. It appears that you're trying to generate the mid point of the 4 corners in the first loop. In the second loop, you then generate the mid points of the vertical sides of the quad. (Though it seems like at least one of the points will be uninitialized when this happens.) And the third loop generates the mid points of the horizontal sides. Finally, you make a final pass to ensure that none of the values are out of range. Then you cut the tile size in half and iterate until you've filled the array.

You could do this all in one loop, I believe. I have to admit that I don't actually know C#, so this will be a little pseudo-codey. Sorry about that. Here's how I've done it the past.

First, you need a structure that holds the coordinates of a rectangle. Something like this:

```
struct Rect {
    int left;
    int bottom;
    int right;
    int top;
} Rect;
```

Next, we generate the 4 corners of the map with the seed value and put it into a queue.

```
content.Map [ 0, 0 ] = seed;
content.Map [ sideLength, 0 ] = seed;
content.Map [ 0, sideLength ] = seed;
content.Map [ sideLength, sideLength ] = seed;
Queue<Rect> processQueue; // A queue to hold elevation data
Rect firstRect = { 0, 0, sideLength, sideLength };
processQueue.add (firstRect);
```

Now we'll pull a record out of the queue, divide it into 4 smaller rectangles, set the values of those positions in the map, and add the 4 smaller rectangles back into the queue.

```
// Divide each rect and add it back to the queue
int numPasses = log2(sideLength);
while (numPasses > 0)
{
    int numElements = processQueue.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
    {
        // Get the next Rect out of the queue
        Rect nextRect = processQueue.dequeue();

        // Set the center point to the average of the 4 corners
        int midX = (nextRect.left + nextRect.right) / 2;
        int midY = (nextRect.bottom + nextRect.top) / 2;
        content.Map [ midX, midY ] = average (content.Map, Rect); 

        // Divide it into 4 smaller rectangles
        Rect rect1 = { nextRect.left, nextRect.bottom, midX, midY };
        Rect rect2 = { midX, nextRect.bottom, nextRect.right, midY };
        Rect rect3 = { nextRect.left, midY, midX, nextRect.top };
        Rect rect4 = { midX, midY, nextRect.right, nextRect.top };

        // Set the values of the midpoints of the 4 edges
        int randomOffset = random.Next(offset * 2) - offset;
        content.Map [ midX, nextRect.bottom ] = 
            ((content.Map [ nextRect.left, nextRect.bottom ] +
            content.Map [ nextRect.right, nextRect.bottom) / 2) + 
            randomOffset;
        //... do the same for the mid point on the top, the left, and the right

        // Add the 4 smaller rects to the queue
        processQueue.add (rect1);
        processQueue.add (rect2);
        processQueue.add (rect3);
        processQueue.add (rect4);
    }
    numPasses--;
}
```

In this case the `average()` function calculates the average at the 4 corners of the passed-in rectangle:

```
int average (MapType m, Rect r)
{
    return (m [ r.left, r.bottom] +
            m [ r.left, r.top ] +
            m [ r.right, r.bottom ] +
            m [ r.right, r.top ]) / 4;
}
```

You can also clamp the part where you calculate the midpoint so you don't ever go above the max or below the minimum if you need to.

I should note that this will only hit every element in your `map` array if the dimensions are powers of 2. I believe your code had the same limitation, though, if I'm understanding it correctly.